# $connection->query($mysearch) not working

Tags: php, mysqli

The error occurs like that, when i try to connect to DB to search something, it doesn't connects... here is the code below

```
$connection = new mysqli($db_server,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if($connection->connect_errno)
{
    die ("Connection Failed");
}

$selcap = "SELECT * FROM captcha_codes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $seldcap = $connection->query($selcap);
    if($seldcap === true)
    {
        while ($capdata = $seldcap->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
        {
            $imglink = $capdata['image'];
            $idcap = $capdata['id'];
            $codecap = $capdata['code'];
        }
    } else {
        $msgreg = "Couldn't connect to Captcha, please contact admin!";
    }
```

The result is **Couldn't connect to Captcha, please contact admin!**

Comment: If u run in phpmyadmin `SELECT * FROM captcha_codes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` what happened??

Comment: EHEM, i didn't know that, gotta test

Comment: Its working! (In PHPMyAdmin)

Comment: Also chk `echo $seldcap->num_rows` if connection is fine after this line `$seldcap = $connection->query($selcap);`

Comment: `if($seldcap === true)` will never be reached because `mysqli::query()` returns `mysqli_result` or false on failure.

Comment: @devpro , it is printing 1 as i type `echo seldcap->num_rows;` ... seems its working till it... and it seems the error is in `if($seldcap === true) {}`

Comment: @sebastianForsberg, yeah i found out the fault... but can you guide with `mysqli_result` ?

Comment: Than use this `if($seldcap->num_rows > 0){your while}else{your error}`

Comment: @devpro , thank you .. now i got the problem... you are awesome!! thanks... instead of making sure with `true` .. i should use `num_rows` for it XD happy coding!

Comment: U r welcome posted as answer too. Chk it

Answer (score 0):

Use the less strict `==` comparison here: `if($seldcap === true)`, that should solve the issue.

So the condition would look like: `if($seldcap == true)`

As mentioned by others, you could also check the number of results as well.

See the docs for [mysqli::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for more information on the results of that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check either query returns result or not use [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) :

```
$seldcap = $connection->query($selcap);
if($seldcap->num_rows > 0)
{
     //your while stuff
}
else{
    //your error stuff
}
```